# How do I display an image with correct size from Facebook using Graph API iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, swift3

I'm trying to get a 1920*1080 image (cover picture) from Facebook Graph API (Swift 3), but the data I get from Facebook is just a square part of the full image, that fills the full image view.

Is it better to use FBSDKGraphRequest ? The docs provided by Facebook did not help me, do anyone know how to use it ?

```
let imageView: UIImageView = {
    // 1920/1080 = 1.7777
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 200 * 1.7777, height: 200))
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true

    return imageView
}()

func getImageFromFB(){
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/\(self.fbId!)/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1")
    //let url = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/\(self.fbId!)/picture?width=1920&height=1080&return_ssl_resources=1") //I tried this too...
    let data = NSData(contentsOf:url! as URL)
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
}
```

Comment: Does the profile in question have such a large profile picture uploaded?

Comment: I'd advise to download the image using `URLRequest` or `Alamofire`